# Can't access directory Tensorflow Google Colab

Tags: python, keras, google-colaboratory, tensorflow2.0, kaggle

Sorry I'm new to Tensorflow`2.1 and`GoogleColab`. And I don't understand why I have this error :

My code :

```
%tensorflow_version 2.x

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

print(tf.__version__)

import pathlib
import os

path_data_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file(origin='https://www.kaggle.com/c/dogs-vs-cats/download/0iMGwZllApFLiU35zX78%2Fversions%2Fm5lLqMS0KLfxJUozn3gR%2Ffiles%2Ftrain.zip',fname='train',untar= True)
data_dir = pathlib.Path(path_data_dir)

entries = os.listdir(data_dir)
for entry in entries:
   print(entry)
```

And I have this error (I tried to mount a `GoogleDrive` folder and I have access

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-88f88035f225> in <module>()
     12 data_dir = pathlib.Path(path_data_dir)
     13 
---> 14 entries = os.listdir(data_dir)
     15 for entry in entries:
     16    print(entry)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/root/.keras/datasets/train'
```

Thanks a lot for your help

Lily

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming this is because of the different file system structure between a normal Linux machine and the runtime hosted by Google Colab.

As a workaround, pass the `cache_dir='/content'` argument to the `get_file` function to be as follows: `path_data_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file(origin='https://www.kaggle.com/c/dogs-vs-cats/download/0iMGwZllApFLiU35zX78%2Fversions%2Fm5lLqMS0KLfxJUozn3gR%2Ffiles%2Ftrain.zip',fname='train',untar= True, cache_dir='/content')`

Be aware that the returned value `path_data_dir` is a full path to the file, so the function call `os.list_dir(data_dir)` will fail since `data_dir` points to a file and not a directory.
To fix this, change `entries = os.listdir(data_dir)` to `entries = os.listdir(data_dir.parent)`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is simply a bad link to download data finally... On google colab I can't see correctly the downloaded file (because I can't see folders...) but I tried later on a computer and It's juste the link.